# Similarity of the geometry according to number of nodes and their coordinate values

Tags: python-3.x, pca, computational-geometry

**My question is:** If number of nodes in both geometries are same and coordinates are also same (ordering of coordinates might different), can I conclude that both geometries are same?

I have two sets of coordinates (X and Y) of a geometry. I have counted number of nodes available in both geometries and also have coordinates.

I checked whether second geometry coordinates are all available in first cooridnates or not using below line of code and as a result, I got `'Yes'`.

```
new_coordi1 = [(0.26, 0.27), (0.56, 1.22), (1.51, 0.93), (1.21, -0.03), (0.92, -0.98), (1.87, -1.28), (2.17, -0.33), (2.47, 0.63), (-0.04, -0.69), (-0.34, -1.64), (-1.29, -1.34), (-0.99, -0.39), (-0.7, 0.57), (-1.65, 0.86), (-1.95, -0.09), (-2.25, -1.05), (-1.35, 1.82), (-0.4, 1.52)]

new_coordi2 = [(0.26, 0.27), (0.56, 1.22), (1.51, 0.93), (1.21, -0.03), (0.92, -0.98), (1.87, -1.28), (2.17, -0.33), (2.47, 0.63), (-0.04, -0.69), (-0.99, -0.39), (-1.29, -1.34), (-0.34, -1.64), (-2.25, -1.05), (-1.95, -0.09), (-1.65, 0.86), (-0.7, 0.57), (-0.4, 1.52), (-1.35, 1.82)]

check = all(item in new_coordi2 for item in new_coordi1)
```

Background of this Question: I have two geometries. These geometries are same and they were oriented in the different way in 2D space. I aligned them using Principal Component Analysis and place both geometries at the common orientation. I want to confirm whether two geometries are same or not.

Comment: Geometry is a branch of mathematics... You need to ask your question using correct terminology. Are you asking about point sets in 2D?

Comment: Yes, point sets which are mentioned in the Question are the coordinates of respective geometry. I would like to know from this coordinates whether two sets of coordinates belong to the same geometry or not?..In this case, I know that, this geometry is same. But I need a solid point to proove that.

Comment: Should I transfer my question to mathematics section of stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach works.

```
new_coordd1 = sorted(new_coordi1 , key=lambda tup: (tup[0],tup[1]) )
new_coordd2 = sorted(new_coordi2 , key=lambda tupp: (tupp[0],tupp[1]) )

new_coordd1 == new_coordd2

>>> True
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a better description than "the geometries are the same to a reordering of the points".

Note that PCA seems overkill. You could just sort the point lexicographically on the coordinates* and compare point-wise.

*Unless the values are noisy.

Comment: So, I should sort both coordinate lists new_coordi1 and new_coordi2 lexicographically and as a results, I will get a new ordering the coordinates..And after obtaining those new coordinates after lexicographical ordering, how would I compare them in order to check whether both sets of coordinates belong to same geometry or not?

Comment: @Urvesh: compare the coordinates. What is so mysterious about "same geometry" ???

Comment: From the first answer, I later understood your suggestions. I already applied Sorted function and compare the coordinates. I think you forgot to check my answer below. it would have been better if you checked that answer.